# Angular, Storybook: Digest method not supported

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, storybook

I upgraded to Angular 14 and I can't get storybook to build successfully.

Receiving below error :

```
99% done plugins webpack-hot-middlewarewebpack built preview c4fd3adfedabce8e8e4b in 28712ms
WARN Force closed manager build
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from /node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Digest method not supported
at /node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/loader.js:81:18
at processResult (/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack5/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:701:19)
at /node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack5/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:807:5
at /node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:399:11
at /node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:251:18
at context.callback (/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:124:13)
at /node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/loader.js:81:9
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Digest method not supported
```

Here are the relevant packages I have installed:

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "14.2.0",
"@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "14.0.0",
"@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "14.0.0",
"@angular-eslint/template-parser": "14.0.0",
"@angular/cli": "~14.2.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "14.2.0",
"@angular/language-service": "14.2.0",
"@storybook/angular": "6.5.11",
"@storybook/builder-webpack5": "6.5.11",
"@storybook/manager-webpack5": "6.5.11",
```

Comment: Have you tried this? https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/19201

Comment: @Roy : Yes. I have tried the solution suggested in the mentioned link and still receiving same error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
Just try:

1. delete the node_modules folder
2. delete package-lock.json
3. npm cache clean --force
4. npm i